# Duplicates within output of an inner join

Tags: postgresql

I am joining two tables within PostgreSQL. One table is my raw adwords data (adwords_final.)  The second table is simply just a reference to the "campaigns" column that need to be reported on.  These references occur only once per campaign while the adwords data contains multiple entries per campaign as there is the factor/column of date.

I have used the following query to output this to a csv file

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM adwords_final INNER JOIN mk_kw ON "mk_kw"."Key"  =  "adwords_final"."Key") TO 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report Outputs\adwords_final.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

The problem is that my new csv file contains far to many duplicates.   Am I using the correct command here or should I switch to something like a loop?

Columns within adwords final ;

```
Week    Keyword state   Keyword Campaign    Ad group    Status  Max. CPC    Impressions Interactions    Interaction Types   Interaction Rate    Avg. Cost   Cost    Clicks  Avg. position   Conversions Quality score   Ad relevance    Landing page experience Expected clickthrough rate  Qual. score (hist.) Ad relevance (hist.)    Landing page experience (hist.) Expected clickthrough rate (hist.)  Search Impr. share  Match type  First position CPC  Top of page CPC First page CPC  Impressions with average ctr    Impressions with above average ctr  Impressions with below average ctr  Impressions with below average lp exp   Impressions with average lp exp Impressions with above average lp exp   Impressions with below average Ad Rel   Impressions with  average ad rel    Impressions with above average ad rel   QSxIMP  Key
```

Columns within mk_kw

```
 Language   Network Main Keyword    Cluster Keyword 1   Match Type  Key
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report 
Outputs\adwords_final.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER encoding 'windows-1251';
COPY (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM adwords_final LEFT JOIN mk_kw ON "mk_kw"."Key"  =  
"adwords_final"."Key") TO 'C:\Users\iantu\Desktop\Performance Marketing\Report 
Outputs\adwords_final.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```